# Keep getting "Connected to an idle instance" in 18c when trying to connect to database

Tags: connectivity, oracle-18c

I installed  Oracle Database 18c yesterday and then installed Oracle Application Express v20.1. Everything was perfect and I was able to work on Apex too.

Then I shutdown the computer and today I cannot connect to the database. Yesterday when I connected to the database I got `Connected`, but now I keep getting `Connected to an idle instance`. When I issued the command `startup` I got the following errors:

> ```
> ORA-00838: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 3256M
> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
> ```

Environment : Windows 10 Pro x64, 8GB RAM, AMD R5 1600 Processor, Installed on Samsung PM961 256GB NVMe

Comment: Did you try setting the `MEMORY_TARGET` parameter?

Comment: @Johnakahot2use Sorry for the late reply. Yes I tried. But I cannot execute a query without connecting to the DB.

Comment: So you can't execute step 3.? What error message do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

If the environemnt variables `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_BASE` are set, then you should be able to connect to an `IDLE INSTANCE` with SQLPlus.

```
C:\> sqlplus sys@<SID> as sysdba
```

When connected you then create a editable PFILE copy of the instances current SPFILE (run time configuration). Before that be sure to copy the current editable PFILE to some safe locaiton. If you don't have an SPFILE then skip to step 5.

> **Notice:**
>   Please replace the `<SID>` placeholder I used in my commands with the SID of your actual Oracle instance, and of course the paths to the local SPFILE and PFILE should reflect your actual paths of your installation.

## Configuring Oracle Memory Settings

1. Save the initial PFILE that is created after a setup

   ```
   C:\> COPY C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\init<SID>.ORA C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\init<SID>_backup.ORA
   ```
2. Save any current PFILE that may be laying around

   ```
   C:\> COPY C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\pfile_<SID>.ORA C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\pfile_<SID>_backup.ORA
   ```
3. Log into idle instance

   ```
   C:\> sqlplus sys@<SID> as sysdba
   ```
4. Create a PFILE (modifiable configuration file) from current SPFILE (run-time configuration file)

   ```
   SQL> CREATE PFILE = 'C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\pfile_<SID>.ORA' from SPFILE = 'C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\spfile_<SID>.ORA';
   ```
5. Shutdown the idle instance

   ```
   SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
   ```
6. In an editor open your current PFILE C:\Oracle\admin\\pfile\pfile_.ORA or the INIT_.ORA file and locate these parameters:

   ```
   *.memory_max_target=0
   *.memory_target=0
   ```

   These parameters are set when using [Automatic Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-8F54391B-D42A-4FDA-9D12-E1F81FD113EA). If these are both set to `0` (like above) then you are using [Automatic Shared Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-3CEA1AB5-4850-4064-9823-F62C500A579F). You will have to set the following parameters instead:

   ```
   *.sga_max_size=0
   *.sga_target=0
   ```

   Either of these value pairs should be set. If not, then modify the `memory_max_target` and `memory_target` parameters to something like `4G`. Save the configuration file and...
7. Start the Oracle instance using the freshly created PFILE.

   ```
   C:\> sqlplus sys@<SID> as sysdba
   SQL> STARTUP PFILE='C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\pfile_<SID>.ORA';
   ```
8. When instance is running, create the run-time configuration file.

   ```
   SQL> CREATE SPFILE='C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\spfile_<SID>.ORA' FROM PFILE='C:\Oracle\admin\<SID>\pfile\pfile_<SID>.ORA';
   ```
9. When the SPFILE has been created shutdown the instance.

   ```
   SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
   ```
10. Restart the instance which should use the freshly create SPFILE (run-time configuration).

    ```
    C:\> sqlplus sys@<SID> as sysdba
    SQL> STARTUP
    ```

And you should be on your way.